# Split node value with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath-2.0

Is there some kind of `split()` function in XPath?
Say I have this XML:

```
<root>
   <path>C:\folder\filename</path>
</root>
```

And I want to retrieve `filename`, how can I do this? I know I can get the node value like this:

```
//path/text()
```

How can I get only the filename? (I know there is a `concat()` function, so maybe there is a `split()` function?)

Comment: Good question, +1. Besides the good answers you've got, see my answer for two other possible solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have an xpath-2.0 capable API, you can solve this in two ways:

**replace technique**

Try using:

```
fn:replace(string,pattern,replace)
```

e.g.

```
fn:replace(//path/text(),".*/","")
```

**tokenize technique**

You may get some mileage from tokenize:

```
fn:tokenize(string,pattern)
```

e.g. (thanks to Martin)

```
tokenize(/root/path, '\\')[last()]
```

[w3schools xml processing "xsl functions" documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp#string)

Comment: Yes, `tokenize(/root/path, '\\')[last()]` allows that but note that both replace and tokenize are XPath 2.0 and not available in XPath 1.0 so you need an XPath 2.0 implementation like Saxon 9 (http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't work out whether last applied to dynamically generated collections.

Answer (score 1):

**While I would use**:

```
tokenize(/*/*, '\\')[last()]
```

**there are also numerous other ways to obtain the desired string**:

```
  codepoints-to-string
    (reverse
      (string-to-codepoints
         (substring-before
            (codepoints-to-string
                 (reverse
                    (string-to-codepoints(/*/*)
                  )
              ),
              '\'
            )
          )
       )
     )
```

**Or**:

```
  substring(/*/*,
            index-of(string-to-codepoints(/*/*),
            string-to-codepoints('\')
            )
            [last()]
          + 1
           )
```